# sanity start won't log me in

Tags: reactjs, sanity

Did `sanity upgrade` -> `npm install` -> `sanity init` -> `sanity start`.
I was given `localhost:3333` link. Was able to try either **Google** or **Github** when logging in but it just goes back to login screen with choices every after selecting the user. However, on lower right it always says `Connected to Dev Server`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brave browser seems to have a bug that's preventing the log-in. Try it on another browser. Chrome has worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Brave browser** works the only thing you have to do is to switch off **Brave Shields**. When you off the shields you get logged in no need to use another browser when Brave as no adds.